# 'Less salty' / 'not salty enough'-- which is more idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-request

I hear native speakers say:

> The soup is a bit **too salty.**

But I have never heard the **opposite** from them.

Do they say, **less salty,** **not salty enough** or something else?

Which one is more natural?

Answer (score 4):

You would only use **less salty** if there were an explicit or implied **than** clause.

> This soup is less salty than the soup we had yesterday - *explicit*
> We had some very salty soup yesterday. This is less salty - *implicit*

If you don't want or need a **than** clause, you would say

> The soup is not salty enough
> The soup needs more salt.

Comment: Another possible phrasing for the case in the question might be “This soup lacks salt.” or “This soup is lacking in salt.”

Answer (score 0):

English does not have a phrase that can substitute for the bolded portion of your sentence and have the opposite meaning. To describe something as too salty, you would need a sentence rewrite like suggested by the other answers and comments.

English lacks an antonym for salty, so your sentence will require a total rewrite. For example,
"This soup is not salty enough."
Is probably the closest you can get to your original sentence while still reversing your meaning.